# MySQL Order by after SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, sql-order-by

I've worked out the following for a question i have:

```
SELECT Event_id, SUM(Money) AS 'Total Money'
FROM prize
GROUP BY Event_id
ORDER BY 'Total Money' DESC;
```

However it does not order by the total money. If i omit the '   ' marks and call the column Total_Money, it works fine:

```
SELECT Event_id, SUM(Money) AS Total_Money
FROM prize
GROUP BY Event_id
ORDER BY Total_Money DESC
```

Why is this?
Is there a way to call the column Total Money and sort how i want?

Comment: you r using quote ', don't use quote. use ` character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes define a string value, so in your order by you are not saying `order by this column` you are saying `order by the string 'Total Money'` which of course will not work.

If you really want to use the space you can use backticks instead of single quotes like

```
ORDER BY `Total Money`
```

Comment: Thanks klennepette, missed that in my studies somehow.

Answer (score 1):

when you write `SELECT Event_id, SUM(Money) AS Total Money` you gave an alias Total Money to Sum(Money). 
If you write Total Money in quotes then you are taking it as string which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Event_id, SUM(Money) AS `Total Money`
FROM prize
GROUP BY Event_id
ORDER BY `Total Money` DESC;
```

Ordering by 'Total money' basically says ORDER BY some string to MySQL. When you put anything in quotes, you create a string. When creating aliases, handling column names that are named after some of reserved words (as `user` for example) - use backticks:

```
`user`
```